# Having trouble setting up Redis for ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, redis

I am trying to play with redis on my Ubuntu machine and my little script doesn't work. 
I have installed redis gem and tried this little script (I know its pretty small)

```
require 'redis'
redis = Redis.new
```

I get this error :

```
./redis.rb:4: uninitialized constant Redis (NameError)
from redis.rb:2:in `require'
from redis.rb:2
```

when I comment the line 2, I dont get any problem.
How come the class Redis is not recognized?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rename your file to something other than "redis.rb" (try redis_initializer.rb),

```
require 'redis'

redis = Redis.new
```

Comment: just one last question : why redis.rb causes a conflict?

Comment: I believe it's because when you typed "require 'redis'" ruby actually tried loading your file you created called 'redis.rb'. It didn't look for the gem named 'redis', because it found a file called 'redis' in the script's directory. That's my best guess as to why.